# Create view use html before

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in HTML CSS. I need to create view sample photo: [image]

I used code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
attachment{
border-radius:10px;
padding:8px;
display:block;
background:#dadada;
}
attachment::before{
content:"</>";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<attachment id="7ffdba46c1b64aba89b5176469c2bd5b">Code snippet </br> Text, 12 lines</attachment>
</body>
</html>
```

But my result is: [image]

How I can move `</>` to center vertical and all content in `attachment` tag will alight left `</>` same photo?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

attachment{
border-radius: 10px;
padding: 20px;
display: flex;        /* Newly added */
background: #dadada;
align-items: center; /* Newly added */
line-height:2;      /* Newly added */
}
attachment::before{
content:"</>";
padding: 20px;     /* Newly added */
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<attachment id="7ffdba46c1b64aba89b5176469c2bd5b">
Code snippet </br> Text, 12 lines
</attachment>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, but why background:#dadada; not working?

Comment: that is due to " // Newly added "
sorry i wrongly commented the line.
now i updated to " /* Newly added */ "

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<body>
<div>
<table>
<tr style="margin-top: 50%; margin=left: 50%;">
<td>
<attachment id="7ffdba46c1b64aba89b5176469c2bd5b">
</td>
<td>
Code snippet </br> Text, 12 lines</attachment>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

hope it works!

Comment: thank you, but I can't change html, I need change css.

Answer (score 0):

To move the **</>** to center vertical, use the following style rules:

```
attachment::before {
  content:"</>";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Additionaly you need to add some more tags:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #dadada;
  padding: 0.8em 4em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

attachment {
  display:block;
}

attachment::before {
  content:"</>";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <attachment id="7ffdba46c1b64aba89b5176469c2bd5b">
    <p>Code snippet</p>
    <p>Text, 12 lines</p>
  </attachment>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but I can't change HTML, I need change CSS. I have a solution from Mr.Par tha.

Comment: Note that **display: flex** won't work on **IE 11** or earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Add these few CSS in your code. It will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style> 
        attachment {
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 8px;
            display: flex;
            background: #dadada;
            line-height: 2;        /* New css */
            align-items: center;   /* New css */
        }
        attachment::before{
            content:"</>";
            padding-right: 20px:   /* New css */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <attachment id="7ffdba46c1b64aba89b5176469c2bd5b">Code snippet </br> Text, 12 lines</attachment>
</body>
</html>
```